# Joomla Facebook login

Tags: joomla2.5

I am creating a  real state website with joomla 2.5, but I am facing problem with the Facebook login integration. Can anyone suggest me which module or plugin to use?

Comment: The solution to your problem lies in character 16 of line 27. Good luck. (Or in other words: what have you tried?)

Comment: I thought it was a helping site. I am new to joomla, that's why need to ask experts like you. But, for learning if they respond like this, then nothing else to say. but, still thanks :-)

Comment: SO _is_ a site for helping people, but questions need to be _specific_, which yours is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use component [JFBConnect](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/social-web/social-display/facebook-integration/7215). It will support in Joomla 2.5

Comment: Thanks...Last time i tried to use FB Connect graph. And it was showing error something like 403.....

Comment: Check how you could integrate it!

Answer (score 0):

there is also a good and cheap extension [Facebook All](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/authentication-cloud-based/22865) and also free extension avail now